# How to show the user's webcam video without using the video tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, getusermedia

I want to show the stream I get from the user's webcam to a canvas without using a video tag. The reason I want this is to because for some reason  can't show a video stream inside a parent element like a div tag.

Here is my current code

```js
var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
var id = location.search.replace("?","");
// this line is VERY_important
connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';
function start(){
connection.session = {
    audio: {"echoCancellation": true},
    video: true
};

connection.openOrJoin(id);
connection.onstream = function(event) {
  console.log(event)//this contains the Mediastream
  document.body.appendChild(event.mediaElement) // this is the video tag;
};
connection.onUserStatusChanged = function(status) {
    console.log(status)
  if(status.status=="offline"){
    console.log(status.userid)
   document.getElementById(status.userid).remove();
  }
};
}
start();
```

```css
.video{
  width: 35vw;
  height: 35vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 5px;
}
button{
  padding: 15px;
}
.pinBtn{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Start a video meeting</title>
    <script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-blue.min.css" /> 
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I want the video tag in a parent element so that I can add a "Pin" button in the top right corner of the video by making the position absolute

Comment: "for some reason can't show a video stream inside a parent element like a div tag."  Of course you can.

Comment: Please try editing my code and showing the video inside a parent element, the video player appears but the player won't have a video source

Comment: Normally, with WebRTC, you'll get a MediaStream object and set the `srcObject` property of the video element.  I don't know anything about the library you're using, but surely it gives you access to the MediaStream itself, so you can do the same thing.

Comment: Can you please show how to do so?

Comment: Oh ok now I understood what went wrong, I should appendChild instead of adding innerHTML which made the video to show the stream thanks! @Brad

Comment: Please *answer* this question, and accept the answer. We're really trying to create a good repository of questions and answers for [tag:getusermedia] and related web apis.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can place a video tag within a div tag. To use Javascript to create a video tag and place it in a div tag, use `.createElement()` then `.appendChild()`.